# Apply same style to outer tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have table with me as:

```
<table> 
   <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>
              <span style="background-color:red;color:white">One</span>
         </td>
         <td>
              <span style="background-color:green;font-size:10px">One</span>             
         </td>
         <td>
              <span style="background-color:blue">One</span>             
         </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to apply the same style present in `<span>` to the outer `<td>`.
I am new to jquery. How can I achieve this using jquery?
So that the final table will became:

```
<td style="background-color:red;color:white">
      <span style="background-color:red;color:white">One</span>
</td>
<td style="background-color:green;font-size:10px">
       <span style="background-color:green;font-size:10px">One</span>             
</td>
```

Comment: And with outer you mean?

Comment: If you do background color with red then why the inside span is being applied with red where it means nothing. And, do you want to apply red in 1,3,5... etc td and green in 2,4,6... etc td?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble @Ladineko. Please check the edited question.

Comment: @user1808827 you check my answer!

Comment: @SheikhNeyamat: because `<span>` does not cover whole `<td>`, there are some text outside of `<span>` to which I want to apply the same style. Also I am unable to use css classes and I have this HTML in my hand to edit.

Comment: hey man every body is answering tell them if your problem got solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr` method:

```
$('td').attr('style', function(){
   return $('span', this).attr('style')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V5FuF/

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("span").each(function(){
         $(this).parent().attr("style", $(this).attr("style"));
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QaxKS/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span").each( function() {
var color = $(this).attr("style");
$(this).parent("td").attr("style", function() {
return color;
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ns9rh/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span").each(function(){
         $(this).parent().attr("style", 
         $(this).attr("style"));
    });
```